# What is the difference between int& name and int &name in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was wondering what is the difference between int& name and int &name if there is any. One example:

```
   for (auto& c : s) {...}
   for (auto &c : s) {...}
```

Comment: nothing.Did you find something?

Comment: You could also write `auto&c` or `auto   &             c`.

Comment: Just style difference.

Comment: But be careful. Discussions about where the whitespace belongs have already triggered wars.

Comment: @manni66 Yes, and the ampersand definitely belongs *with* the type. Fight me.